# Understanding memory allocation for TList<RecordType>

Tags: delphi, memory-management, delphi-2010

I have to store a TList of something that can easily be implemented as a record in Delphi (five simple fields).  However, it's not clear to me what happens when I do `TList<TMyRecordType>.Add(R)`.

Since R is a local variable in the procedure in which I create the my TList, I assume that the memory for it will be released when the function returns.  Does this leave an invalid record pointer in the list?  Or does the list know to copy-on-assign?  If the former, I assume I would have to manually manager the memory for R with New() and Dispose(), is that correct?

Alternatively, I can "promote" my record type to a class type by simply declaring the fields public (without even bothering with making them formal properties).  Is that considered OK, or ought I to take the time to build out the class with private fields and public properties?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplified: records are blobs of data and are passed around by value - i.e. by copying them - by default. `TList<T>` stores values in an array of type T. So, `TList<TMyRecordType>.Add(R)` will copy the value `R` into the array at position `Count`, and increment the `Count` by one. No need to worry about allocation or deallocation of memory.

More complex issues that you usually don't need to worry about: if your record contains fields of a string type, an interface type, a dynamic array, or a record which itself contains fields of one of these types, then it's not just a simply copy of data; instead, CopyRecord from System.pas is used, which ensures that reference counts are updated correctly. But usually you don't need to worry about this detail unless you are using `Move` to shift the bits around yourself, or doing similar low-level operations.

Comment: The key point is that a record is a value type and an instance of a class is a reference type. One really needs to understand the distinction.

Comment: And you can also pass pointers to a record type... and have all reference typing benefits. If your records are maintained in memory (in a global untouched list or in a memory mapped file), this is a very convenient way. But it's perhaps a bit technical, and not the "standard" use of Delphi. Users should better use classes, and records only if it does make a difference.

Comment: @Barry: Does it then follow that in a procedure I can declare R: TMyRecordType and repeatedly overwrite its fields and Add() it to the list, creating a new record in the list each time?  Without having to allocate a New(R) each time?  And when is the memory for those copied records internal to the TList released?

Comment: @Larry Yes, it's a value type - it behaves the same way as Integer or Double. The memory is released after the items are removed from the list.

Comment: @David: Yes, but will those items be removed automatically when the list itself is freed?  Or do I have to do it before freeing the list?

Comment: @Larry They will be freed by the list. Really, just pretend that you are using Integer rather than TMyRecordType. The lifetime semantics are identical.

Comment: @Larry You don't need to New them. If you were using a plan old fashioned TList then you would but this is Generics.Collections.TList<> that we are talking about.

Comment: Aha!  The concept I was missing is that TList<> has different memory management behavior that TList.  Thanks for making that clear.

Comment: @Larry Yes this is the huge benefit of generics and the type safety that it brings. Of course, Barry who answered, I believe, was the chief architect of the generics implementation in native Delphi. So he knows a fair bit about this!!!

Comment: @David - not chief architect. The design was guided by .NET generics, and the spec was written by Danny Thorpe before he left. They were primarily implemented by Yooichi Tagawa. I implemented the generics library, but not the compiler implementation, in very little time before release (some bugs got in to begin with), as my main task at the time was anonymous methods.

Comment: @Barry Kelly Thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding. I know that Allen and Yooichi are working on dcc64 (I follow their tweets). It would be very interesting to know what you are working on at the moment, if the powers that be permitted that information to leave the organisation!